# Creating a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dynamic

Is it possible to the do the following, if not is there a better way to do what i am trying to accomplish?

## Person.cs

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
        }
```

I want to do this part so i can dynamically call the method based on which ever part of the list it is on, i'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this.

```
        public void Assign(string k, string v)
        {
            k = v;
        }

public string getKeyValue(string k, int w, char d)
    {
        string[] value = k.Split(d);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string part in value)
        {
            if (i == w)
            {
                k = part;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return k;
    }
    }
```

And then in code behind call it like this

## Default.aspx.cs

```
List<string> initList = new List<string> 
{ 
    "ID = 1", "Name = this is a test", "Zip = 5","ID = 2", "Name = this is a second test", "Zip = 10"        
};

List<object> myList = new List<object>();

Person prs = new Person();
foreach (string txt in initList)
{
    string key = prs.getKeyValue(txt,0,'=');
    string val = prs.getKeyValue(txt,1,'=');

    prs.Assign(key,val);

}

 myList.Add(prs);
```

Comment: What in the world are you trying to accomplish?  Could you give some backstory?

Comment: Can't you come up with a better title? Creating _what kind of_ class?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i am essentialy trying to create a class to be able to create a list of objects that i can then bind it to a datagrid. But currently i am having an issue trying to come up with the class part or at least trying to get it to work

Comment: You might want to work on some of your variable names. It would definitely help others understand.

Comment: your right, i will :)

Comment: @user2593590: `"i am essentialy trying to create a class to be able to create a list of objects"` - Can't you just use a `List<>` of that object?  It's not clear what you're trying to do or why.  Are you trying to set properties on your object by using the string representation of the property's name perhaps?

Comment: yes exactly what i am trying to do, just didn't know how to explain it

Comment: In that case you'll want to investigate Reflection, but it's a really advanced topic.

Comment: Is there something simpler or easier i can do for what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: how can k = v in Assign method "assign" anything?

Comment: yeah, i know it looks weird, but what i am trying to accomplish, is while it loops through the list instead of me doing

prs.ID = 1
prs.Name = john
and so on i can do the following

prs.Assign(k,v)

Example while it loops through the list

prs.Assign(ID, 1);
prs.Assign(Name, john);

and so on, while it loops throug the list

Comment: setting property values via reflection is not advanced. its simple. but im sure you are completely lost and misunderstood some concepts. im sure your real problem is something else.

Comment: @user2593590 - Ok, for what you want, don't write a method. Write a constructor like Person(string id, string name) & try using new Person(1, John) & then put push each of them to a list.

Comment: yeah reflection looks very complicated, can you provide maybe an example on how i would use it with what i am trying to do

Comment: yeah, i thought about doing that but the problem was the list that i have, don't know how i would be able to say, push the 3 first elements of the list into the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking on it some, I think you think that passing strings is a better way of doing assignment:

```
List<string> initList = new List<string> 
{ 
    "ID = 1", "Name = this is a test", "Zip = 5","ID = 2", "Name = this is a second test", "Zip = 10"        
};
```

What are the problems with doing this instead:

```
var people = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person()
    {
        ID=1,
        Name="this is a test",
        Zip=5
    },
    new Person()
    {
        ID=2,
        Name="this is a second test",
        Zip=10
    }
};
```

The second option has intellisense, breaks at compile-time if there are invalid entries.  It's not as clever looking, and there's some more typing (maybe), but this way is much less error prone.

Now, you can loop through your List of Person, and instead of doing some generic operation like `Assign`, you can do descriptive things like `ShowZipCode` or `DisplayName`.  This would result in much more readable, understandable and (most importantly) maintainable code.

**edit**
Ok, this'll be easy:

Read the entire flat file into a string we'll call `flatFileData`.

Then split it using the comma:

`var arrayOfProperties = flatFileData.Split(',');`

Now, nested loop to read the data in threes (since you have three properties):

```
var people=new List<Person>();
for(int i=0;i<arrayOfProperties.Length;i=i+3)
{
    var rawId=arrayOfProperties[i];
    var rawName=arrayOfProperties[i+1];
    var rawZip=arrayOfProperties[i+2];

    // Get the data out of the raw entry
    var id=rawId.Substring(rawId.LastIndexOf('=')).Trim();
    var name=rawName.Substring(rawName.LastIndexOf('=')).Trim();
    var zip=rawZip.Substring(rawZip.LastIndexOf('=')).Trim();

    // Make a constructor for Person that takes these values
    people.Add(new Person(id,name,zip));
}
```

The rawId.Substring... part could be refactored out into a method, but didn't want to make the solution more messy than it had to be.  Do you get the gist of what I'm doing?

Comment: I am just showing an example of what the list looks like, but the list i am using is a text file formatted that way

Comment: Could you update your post with a sample of that text file data?  We can work with flat-file object population.  That'll be simple.

Comment: It looks exactly like what i put there, just pretty much about 1000's of entires

Comment: Ok, is the data all on one line, or is it Id,Name,Zip, then new line, then Id,Name,Zip, etc.?

Comment: all one line, these are all horrible lists that my company received and i need to format them and make them look nice and pretty

Comment: Ok, updated my solution with something that I think will work and doesn't need Reflection.

Comment: thats perfect, except for the list is not comma separated, and it they come like this: ID=1 Name=john Zip=10 ID=2 Name=Tim Zip=45, is there a way to do it with a list like this

Comment: Are the names all one-word?  If so, you could split with a space.  If there are spaces in the name, you're going to have trouble.  Can you have it exported to you with comma separation?

Comment: That worked, i implemented it into my code and it works like a champ, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment but I wanted to show some code.

Add a constructor with arguments below.(add more arguments like zipcode if you want to)

```
public Person(string id, string name)
{
    this.ID = id;
    this.Name = name;
}
```

write the method GetKeyValue outside your Person class, may be move it to `Default.aspx.cs`
& To call it inside your foreach loop

```
Person prs;
foreach (string txt in initList)
{
    string key = GetKeyValue(txt,0,'=');
    string val = GetKeyValue(txt,1,'=');

    prs = new Person(key, val);
    myList.Add(prs);
}
```

Comment: I like this way of doing it, but is there a way of doing it without using the constructor

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do it is pretty horrible; as there's lots of possible errors. Here's a very hacky and error prone way of doing it... but it'll give you an idea of how to do it with reflection...

```
List<string> initList = new List<string> 
{ 
    "ID = 1", 
    "Name = this is a test", 
    "Zip = 5", 
    "ID = 2", 
    "Name = this is a second test", 
    "Zip = 10" 
};

List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
Person person = null;
Type type = typeof(Person);
foreach (var str in initList)
{
    var pair = str.Split('=').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
    if (pair[0] == "ID")
    {
        person = new Person();
        list.Add(person);
    }
    if (person != null)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(pair[0]);
        if (property != null)
            property.SetValue(person, pair[1]);
    }
}

foreach (var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item.ID);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I am going to try this now to see how it works, thanks a lot for the example